# Magento2 PLP / SLP - Custom Sort Option doesn't work with ElasticSearch

Tags: magento2.4, elasticsearch, product-sorting, magento-2-commerce

I am facing one issue in my Magento 2.4.0 Commerce project.
Please let me know if anyone has faced this before and you have any solution.

It is coming when I try to add a non-product attribute or custom option in the sorting options.

Follow this tutorial to add new option in sorting PLP:
https://meetanshi.com/blog/add-magento-2-sort-by-price-for-low-to-high-high-to-low-options/

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception): {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [latest] in order to sort on","index_uuid":"ZoVTK7mPTauqfafOPbywSg","index":"magento2_product_1_v173"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"magento2_product_1_v173","node":"ANhpdXFGTHuC8DLaa95lyw","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [latest] in order to sort on","index_uuid":"ZoVTK7mPTauqfafOPbywSg","index":"magento2_product_1_v173"}}]},"status":400}

```
{
"error": {
    "root_cause": [
        {
            "type": "query_shard_exception",
            "reason": "No mapping found for [personalized] in order to sort on",
            "index_uuid": "s182utskRnO318HifoNvAg",
            "index": "magento2_product_1_v26"
        }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
        {
            "shard": 0,
            "index": "magento2_product_1_v26",
            "node": "OUf9MyxzRheyO02JEjaURA",
            "reason": {
                "type": "query_shard_exception",
                "reason": "No mapping found for [personalized] in order to sort on",
                "index_uuid": "s182utskRnO318HifoNvAg",
                "index": "magento2_product_1_v26"
            }
        }
    ]
},
"status": 400
}
```

at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php: 675)